# Spotify's Web Playback SDK - Can users other than the user who created the player listen through the SDK?

Tags: sdk, spotify

I want to create a web app where I use Spotify's Web Playback SDK to create a player and play music in the browser from another Spotify client (e.g. my Spotify app on my phone or Spotify app on my computer) and also enable other users who are on my website to listen to what's being played live.

Is this possible to do through the Web Playback SDK? If not, how would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

If the playlist is public then you could allow your users to sign into the website to get a Spotify Token you can then use with the Web Playback SDK, since they log into their own Spotify account, should they have one, it will allow them to listen to your Playlist.

However you would need to have additional code / events to ensure they're in the correct track and position. But you could have something to set this, such as something on your machine which publishes the track and position you're at every so often so you can then have it set the current playback track and position in their web player - but that's something you'd have to figure out is possible, but at least to listen to the same Playlist would work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try and figure out how to track and the position of the track and sync it with the player